# Kaomoji characters on Text object

Tags: premiere

I'm having problems rendering [Kaomoji](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kaomoji) characters using Premiere's text tool, I'm working on a windows environment. if I copy-paste the Kaomoji below:

> ٩*ˊᗜˋو

It is rendered like this:

---

[image]

---

On the effects panel it is shown properly though:

---

[image]

---

I've tried many fonts even installed fonts that claim to support Kaomoji but the issue persist. Maybe I should tweak some text configuration setting which I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Get them to work in TextEdit first (assuming you're on a mac).
Check exactly which font works in TextEdit.
Then try that font in Premiere when copying the characters from TextEdit using "paste and match style" into a text box.

If that doesn't work, you might have to export from textedit as a PDF, then import the PDF in Premiere (but this means the text will no longer be editable in Premiere).

Comment: I'm working on windows environment :(

Comment: apologies - you did say that.

Comment: No, I didn't, I edited my post after your answer :) regardless, no need to apologize maybe your answer is usefull for other users with my problem.